# Why do I get "Undefined" only on the "Vertical" Grid?

Tags: javascript

Problem:

When I get to the end of the Grid it gives me an Error :-/

The X axis is fine, the problems occur then I move "over the end" of TOP and BOTTOM.

This code works:

```
if(new_data[1] == "right"){
            // If New Grid Location is Empty
            if(grid[player_y][player_x  + 1] == 0){
            grid[player_y][player_x] = 0;
            player_x = player_x + 1;
            grid[player_y][player_x] = 1;
            socket.emit("message", "move," + "right");
            }
```

And this one does not:

```
if(new_data[1] == "up"){

        // If New Grid Location is Empty
        if(grid[player_y - 1][player_x] == 0){
        grid[player_y][player_x] = 0;
        player_y = player_y - 1;
        grid[player_y][player_x] = 1;
        socket.emit("message", "move," + "up");
```

It says the error is "Cant == 0 of Undefined"

I assume that the Problem lies in the First Array being less then 0 and therefore giving a Undefined Error on the Second Array..

**I fixed this by creating a "Wall" at the X Edges:**

```
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
grid[0][i] = 1;
}
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
grid[19][i] = 1;
}
```

But why does it not give an Error when I try to access a "undefined" of the Second Array?

Comment: Are you sure when you add 1 you are not adding to something that is NaN ?

Comment: Why was my comment deleted if this wasn't migrated?

Comment: Ditto.. No idea why

Comment: It wasn't migrated because the OP is unable to ask questions on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because in here `if (grid[player_y - 1][player_x] == 0)` you actually do `if (grid[0 - 1][player_x] == 0)` at some point. Accessing -1 element of array gives you the error.

You need to check your bounds first, before testing with array. Probably like so:

`if (player_y >= 0 && player_y < width) && (grid[player_y - 1][player_x] == 0)`

*I'm not entirely familiar with how JS handles out of range in arrays, is it possible that when you access x+1 JS increases the arrays length or accesses next element at [y+1,0]*

Comment: Yes. It's because you can access any property of anything (including arrays), and if it doesn't exist, you'll just get an undefined value.  But if you try to use the undefined value as an array... boom!